# T-SQL: querying table while populating it in a second session

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
, some_column varchar(10)
, some_other_column datetime
, yet_another_one bigint
, bazillion_other_columns_goes_here ...
);
```

Now, in SSMS I execute:

```
BULK INSERT T1 FROM 'E:\blahblahblah.dat';
```

blahblahblah.dat is relatively large; the BULK INSERT takes over 40 minutes to complete.

While the BULK INSERT is still running, I open a second session to the same server.database and go:

```
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

As expected, I get no rows on the output.

Then I try:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WITH(NOLOCK);
```

This time I get a full set of rows imported so far, also as expected.

However, when I run:

```
SELECT id FROM t1 WITH(NOLOCK);
```

... I get no rows.

If I select any columns other than id, I get partial results. But when I select id *only*, I get nothing. Unless of course the BULK INSERT completes and everything is back to normal.

Any ideas why this is happening? Why does SELECT * return rows while SELECT id does not?

Comment: To confirm, `id` is not an IDENTITY column?
And table `t1` is not the same as `T1` in case sensitive collations

Comment: Indeed, it is not an identity, and this is all the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas why this is happening?

Because you're using NOLOCK.  So there are absolutely no guarantees about what you'll get.  Perhaps the non-leaf levels of the index haven't been built yet.  But who knows.  The results are undocumented, and could change at any time.